# TypeError at /comments/post/ get_comment_create_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'site_id'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with **django-comments-xtd** when I try to work with django 1.9. I'm following [this](https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) tutorial. When I work with Django 1.8 everything is fine. But if I use Django 1.9 I get the error when I send a message.

`TypeError at /comments/post/
get_comment_create_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'site_id'`

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/post/

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pagedown',
 'crispy_forms',
 'markdown_deux',
 'django_comments',
 'django_comments_xtd',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
42.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_comments/views/comments.py" in post_comment
108.     comment = form.get_comment_object(site_id=get_current_site(request).id)

File "/home/olga/.virtualenvs/my_site/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_comments/forms.py" in get_comment_object
121.         new = CommentModel(**self.get_comment_create_data(site_id=site_id))

Exception Type: TypeError at /comments/post/
Exception Value: get_comment_create_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'site_id'
```

I set the SITE_ID in settings.py

In theory django-comments-xtd is compatible with django 1.9

I've got the same issue when I work with my own project (dj 1.9). And even when I run the [example](https://github.com/danirus/django-comments-xtd/tree/master/demos/multiple) (dj 1.9)  for tutorial. Everything is fine until I send a message.

Here is **forms.py** of my own app.

```
from django import forms 
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    publish = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']


from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django_comments_xtd.forms import XtdCommentForm

class MyCommentForm(XtdCommentForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'comment' in kwargs:
            followup_suffix = ('_%d' % kwargs['comment'].pk)
        else:
            followup_suffix = ''
        super(MyCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field_obj in self.fields.items():
            if field_name == 'followup':
                field_obj.widget.attrs['id'] = 'id_followup%s' % followup_suffix
                continue
            field_obj.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
            if field_name == 'comment':
                field_obj.widget.attrs.pop('cols')
                field_obj.widget.attrs.pop('rows')
                field_obj.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = _('Your comment')
                field_obj.widget.attrs['style'] = "font-size: 1.1em"
            if field_name == 'url':
                field_obj.help_text = _('Optional')
        self.fields.move_to_end('comment', last=False)
```

**urls.py** of my app

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_list,
    post_update,
    post_delete
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
    url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),    
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),    
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments_xtd.urls')),
    url(r'^', include("blog.urls", namespace ="blog")),      
]


if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [that link](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/issues/115) can help you. I have the same error and it disappeared when I added **kwargs to custom get_comment_create_data() method, as claudep said.

Comment: Where dou you add it?

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados, At my custom Comment form (forms.py file)